# JSpinner with SpinnerDateModel weird behaviour

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

I swear this is so weird. I make a Spinner, set model with new SpinnerDateModel with current date, no limit, and Calendar.MINUTE unit.

As it's said in the documentation:

> Creates a SpinnerDateModel that represents a sequence of dates between
>   start and end. The nextValue and previousValue methods compute
>   elements of the sequence by advancing or reversing the current date
>   value by the calendarField time unit. The start and end parameters can be null to indicate that the range doesn't have an upper or lower bound.

And here is my code:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.JSpinner.DefaultEditor;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.text.DateFormatter;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory;

public class JSpinnerTest {

    public JSpinnerTest() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JSpinner Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner();
        spinner.setModel(new javax.swing.SpinnerDateModel(new Date(), null, null, Calendar.MINUTE));
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

        ((DefaultEditor) spinner.getEditor()).getTextField().setFormatterFactory(new DefaultFormatterFactory(new DateFormatter(format)));


        System.out.println("ORIGINAL VALUE: " + spinner.getValue().toString());

        spinner.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                System.out.println("VALUE: " + ((JSpinner) e.getSource()).getValue().toString());
            }
        });

        frame.add(spinner);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new JSpinnerTest();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But every time I click on the tiny arrow button the date reset to Jan 01 1970. Why?

Example Output:

ORIGINAL VALUE: Thu Dec 06 17:06:13 ICT 2012

VALUE: Thu Jan 01 17:06:00 ICT 1970

VALUE: Thu Jan 01 17:06:00 ICT 1970

VALUE: Thu Jan 01 18:06:00 ICT 1970

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying the date format used by the editor attached to the Spinner. It looks like when you use HH:mm format the rest of the fields are initialized with epoch. If you don't change the format used by the date editor it works as expected.

Comment: Yeah it will work when you change the format to the usual one. But it still only changes the left most part of the string (except when I highlight the other parts). Then what's the purpose of the "calendarField time unit" (last parameter)? And I only wanna show the time. I don't understand why would the developers code it to read the value based on the string? That's ridiculous! They can access the date which is set from the constructor.

Comment: I think the model is behaving properly, the editor is not using current day when converting HH:mm to date. You may need to modify the downstream code to use only hour and minute value from the date returned by the spinner. Or if your downstream code needs full date you can created new date and set hour/minute to it.

Comment: Not in my mind, why would I design a component that has access to the original date instance to depend on the text field's string? If that's the case then I would at least need a parameter that can be set to specify which part of the date that can be changed by the spinner's buttons.

Answer (score 0):

if you put in the dateformat to include the date this doesn't happen, "dd/mm/yy HH:mm". I know that this isn't what your asking, but I would assume that when you dont explicitly state the date it defaults to not using them.